# What is the word(s) to describe someone who has already been to a big city and is not going to behave like a silly country man? describe the opposite?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

What are some words or phrases that describe someone who acts and behaves like a modern city person and is not going to freak out when they go to a big city like New York? How about describing the opposite, someone who has spent their entire life in the countryside or a small town?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "*freak out*" in these scenarios?

Comment: By 'freak out' I mean feeling lost and not knowing how to behave.

Comment: For the second, [country bumpkin](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/country-bumpkin). (The dictionary says 'British English', but search results suggest that it is used in the US too.)

Comment: Could you then say "*they are used to big cities*" or "*they are used to the countryside*"? What kind of a construct are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Aren't all you denizens of the big cities *street* or, in older parlance, *street-wise*?  We bumpkins might be said to be *unpaved-track-wise* but it hardly rolls off the tongue.

Comment: See [The Town Mouse and the Country Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Town_Mouse_and_the_Country_Mouse) and variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hick ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hick)) (derogatory) An awkward, naive, clumsy and/or rude country person.

Agrestic ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agrestic)) Of or pertaining to the fields; rural; rustic, unpolished.

Answer (score 1):

The Americanism **slicker** is not given a caveat in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slicker), but I'd say it's informal if not slang. In fact, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/city-slicker) labels *city slicker* 'informal'. And the 'visiting from the sticks' condition is not referenced, but I can't see a closer match.

> *slicker* ...
>
> (2): [also slickster] b: a city dweller especially of stylish and
> well-groomed appearance or sophisticated mannerisms

......................

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bumpkin) includes as synonyms of **bumpkin** [@Kate Bunting, above] Synonyms for bumpkin

> chawbacon, churl, clodhopper, cornball, countryman, hayseed, hick,
> provincial, rube, rustic, yokel

Answer (score 1):

Country bumpkin is someone who is not used to cities or even urban areas. As for a country bumpkin who has been to a city once or even a few times, you could say they've become 'acclimated' to city life. Basically, they're used to it now. This isn't specific to what you're asking though. Most commonly you would become acclimated to college life or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

***Worldly-wise***, perhaps.

*Having or characterised by worldly wisdom; experienced in the ways of the world.*

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worldly-wise